# ManualResetEvent strange behaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Before asking, I'll first show some code...

```
public partial class Player : UserControl
{
    ManualResetEvent _pauseEvent;
    ManualResetEvent _stopEvent;

    Thread t;

    public Player()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Disposed += (s, a) =>
        {
            Quit();
        };

        _pauseEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        _stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        // Creates the thread...
        t = new Thread(StartText);
        t.IsBackground = false;

        // Starts with thread paused...
        StopPlaying();

        // Let's go!
        t.Start();
    }

    public void StopPlaying()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ordered to stop");
        _pauseEvent.Reset();
    }

    private void ResumePlaying()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ordered to resume");
        _pauseEvent.Set();
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        _pauseEvent.Set();
        _stopEvent.Set();
    }

    public void SetText(string text, bool loop)
    {
        StopPlaying();

        // Here we supose the thread would be stopped!!!! But it's not!!!
        // But when I call StopPlaying() from a button on the form that
        //   contains this usercontrol, everything works as expected

        ...... Do some processing here .....

        ResumePlaying();
    }

    private void StartText()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _pauseEvent.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

            if (_stopEvent.WaitOne(0))
                break;

                do // While LOOP
                {
                        ... Do some process here .....

                        // Verifies if stop requested
                        if (!_pauseEvent.WaitOne(0))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("STOP REQUESTED");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                } while (LOOP);
            }
    }
}
```

My problem is:

When I call StopPlaying() from a button of the form that contains this UserControl, the test made inside the thread detects correctly, but when I call StopPlaying from the SetText() method it doesn't work, as if the event is not resetted.

By the way, the method SetText() is called by another button of the same form.

Comment: This is bad logic for pausing, really hard to follow and debug. Redesign.

Comment: Could be bad logic, but the fact is: the Reset of the event should works every time, but it's not what is happening.

Comment: Almost certainly you have some kind of race condition you're not handling correctly. Possibly related to the lack of any way to know that the thread has in fact been paused (so pausing is pointless...the commanding thread may do all of its work before the commanded thread ever gets far enough to actually wait). However, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say specifically what your bug is. I do agree with the previous comment, there are better ways to deal with pause/resume features; the above design is overly complicated and error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a race condition in your `StartText()` method.  You have `StartText` running on a separate thread and `SetText()` is called from the main UI thread, so what's probably happening is that `SetText()` is resetting and then setting `_pauseEvent` before control is passed back to the other thread.  So as far as `StartText` is concerned the reset never happens.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation to fix? Maybe a `lock` statement?

Comment: @IAbstract In fact, that's what I did. A `lock` solves my problem. Anyway, I'm still curious why a `ManualResetEvent` did ake the trick.